# ''Blotches of diseased, evil gray ...''

Tags: meaning, short-stories, harlan-ellison

> ''Blotches of diseased, evil gray come and go on my surface, as though
> light is being beamed from within.''

---

What does "gray" mean in this sentence? It's from a short story called [''I Have No Mouth And I Must Scream''](https://wjccschools.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/01/I-Have-No-Mouth-But-I-Must-Scream-by-Harlan-Ellison.pdf) by Harlan Ellison.

Comment: It's the same as, say, ***Patches** of **green** appeared on the surface as the cheese went mouldy*. Your example refers to ***gray blotches*** just as mine refers to ***green patches***. You can decide for yourself whether it's the ***gray*** that's "evil and diseased", or the ***blotches*** (to the extent that makes any difference to the meaning).

Comment: It's actually in a good dictionary, eg noun sense 1 or 2 here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gray

Answer (score 3):

> Blotches of diseased, evil gray

A "blotch" is a kind of like a paint splatter on a surface -- an irregularly shaped mark, usually of a single color.

> come and go on my surface,

These blotches tend to appear and fade away.

> as though light is being beamed from within.

The author is saying that the blotches look kind of like they are being projected from inside the beast onto the skin of this beast.